# Reverse engineering a simple list comprehension to its regular form

Tags: python

I'm trying to reverse engineer the below list comprehension but my attempt only generates 1 card.  What am I missing?

```
ranks = [_ for _ in range(2, 11)] + ['JACK', 'QUEEN', 'KING', 'ACE']
suits = ['SPADE', 'HEART ', 'DIAMOND', 'CLUB']

def get_deck():
    return [[rank, suit] for rank in ranks for suit in suits]
```

My attempt:

```
def get_deck():
    for rank in ranks:
        for suit in suits:
            return [rank, suit]
```

Comment: What do you mean with *reverse*?

Comment: What do you mean by reversing list comprehension? Do you mean reverse a list using a list comprehension?

Comment: `return` *returns* control back to the caller, which apparently happens after the first iteration.

Comment: You need to start with an empty list, `lst = []`,  and then in each iteration append to that list (instead of return, use `lst.append([rank, suit])` and return the list at the end.

Comment: I mean reverse engineering a list comprehension to its regular form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` means that you *end* the code path of that function, and optionally that you return a *single* value (the value can of course be a tuple, so you can return multiple values through one value).

If you want to write a *generator function*, `yield` is your friend:

```
def get_deck():
    for rank in ranks:
        for suit in suits:
            yield [rank, suit]
```

If we now call the function, we will obtain a generator object:

```
>>> get_deck()
<generator object get_deck at 0x7f4458438ca8>
```

If you wish to generate a list based on the generator, you can call `list(..)` on the result of the `get_deck()` function:

```
>>> list(get_deck())
[[2, 'SPADE'], [2, 'HEART '], [2, 'DIAMOND'], [2, 'CLUB'], [3, 'SPADE'], [3, 'HEART '], [3, 'DIAMOND'], [3, 'CLUB'], [4, 'SPADE'], [4, 'HEART '], [4, 'DIAMOND'], [4, 'CLUB'], [5, 'SPADE'], [5, 'HEART '], [5, 'DIAMOND'], [5, 'CLUB'], [6, 'SPADE'], [6, 'HEART '], [6, 'DIAMOND'], [6, 'CLUB'], [7, 'SPADE'], [7, 'HEART '], [7, 'DIAMOND'], [7, 'CLUB'], [8, 'SPADE'], [8, 'HEART '], [8, 'DIAMOND'], [8, 'CLUB'], [9, 'SPADE'], [9, 'HEART '], [9, 'DIAMOND'], [9, 'CLUB'], [10, 'SPADE'], [10, 'HEART '], [10, 'DIAMOND'], [10, 'CLUB'], ['JACK', 'SPADE'], ['JACK', 'HEART '], ['JACK', 'DIAMOND'], ['JACK', 'CLUB'], ['QUEEN', 'SPADE'], ['QUEEN', 'HEART '], ['QUEEN', 'DIAMOND'], ['QUEEN', 'CLUB'], ['KING', 'SPADE'], ['KING', 'HEART '], ['KING', 'DIAMOND'], ['KING', 'CLUB'], ['ACE', 'SPADE'], ['ACE', 'HEART '], ['ACE', 'DIAMOND'], ['ACE', 'CLUB']]
```

You can also **built a list in the `get_deck` function**, like:

```
def get_deck():
    result = []
    for rank in ranks:
        for suit in suits:
            result.append([rank,suit])
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse a list by adding `[::-1]` to the end. So you could do your list comprehension and then reverse it. Or just call `reversed` on the list.